# Share Extension loadItemForTypeIdentifier returns error for NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I have the following code to read in passed URLs. I'm testing this with the `Pocket` app and although `hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier` is returning YES for `kUTTypeURL`, trying to load it in returns a error instead stating

> "Unexpected value class."

. If I try to load it as an `id<NSSecureCoding>` item and debug, I find that the passed in object is indeed just the title of the page and not the URL. How do I read the URL?

```
  NSURL *pageURL = nil;
  for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
     if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier: (NSString*) kUTTypeURL]) {
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString*) kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(id <NSSecureCoding> urlItem, NSError *error) {
          if ([((NSObject*)urlItem) isKindOfClass: [NSURL class]]) {
              pageURL = [((NSURL*)urlItem) absoluteString];
          }
        }];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does it work right if you test it with Safari instead of Pocket?

Comment: Yes it does, in fact it works with all other apps that share links / URLs etc. Somehow having issues with Pocket. What's really odd is how it passes the first 'if' condition but then in the second one it fails to grab a valid URL, instead returning the title of the page as plain text. I even tried various other data types like NSData etc, but they all either return nil or the title of the page. I don't see how other apps, like Wunderlist, are able to read the URL from Pocket properly.

Comment: @strangetimes - Did you ever find a solution for this? I've just ran into this exact same issue and have been banging my head against my keyboards trying to figure out how these other apps are getting the URL out of Pocket.

Comment: @jrtilson sadly no - I just gave up. Never found a solution, nor did I get a reply from the devs @ pocket app. It wasn't worth spending more than a few hours of head banging that led me nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for:

```
loadItemForTypeIdentifier(_:options:completionHandler:)
```

You'll see that:

> The type information for the first parameter of your completionHandler
>   block **should be set to the class of the expected type**. For example,
>   when requesting text data, you might set the type of the first
>   parameter to NSString or NSAttributedString. An item provider can
>   perform simple type conversions of the data to the class you specify,
>   such as from NSURL to NSData or NSFileWrapper, or from NSData to
>   UIImage (in iOS) or NSImage (in OS X). If the data could not be
>   retrieved or ***coerced*** to the specified class, an error is passed to the
>   completion block’s.

Maybe you can experiment by coercing to different types?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  __block NSURL *pageURL = nil;
  for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
     if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier: (NSString*) kUTTypeURL]) {
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString*) kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *urlItem, NSError *error) {
          if (urlItem) {
              pageURL = urlItem;
          }
        }];
      }
    }
  }
```

And now if you want take URL of your current site use
`NSString *output = [pageURL absolutestring];`

Output - will be your URL.

Comment: No luck with Pocket.app

Comment: Look then try to change `(NSString*) kUTTypeURL` to the `@"public.url"`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this issue now myself. The Pocket App seems to be the only App which shows this issue. The strange thing is that there are Apps which can get the URL form Pocket. Like for example Firefox for iOS. Firefox is Open Source so I looked at its code (at Github) and found that it is doing exactly the same to get the URL that is shown here. The only difference is that Firefox is written in Swift, and my code (and the one posted here) is Objective C. So I wonder if the Pocket App is doing something strange that is triggering a bug in the Objective C API of the iOS only, so Swift Apps are not affected? I do not have any Swift experience yet, so I haven’t checked if switching to Swift would „solve“ this.

The fact that the method "hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:“ states that there is a URL available but „loadItemForTypeIdentifier:“ can not deliver it, is a clear indication that the iOS itself has a bug here (at least in the Objective C API). But there still must be something special the Pocket App is doing to trigger this bug, because otherwise this would not work in all other Apps.